# %20 being added to the end of url

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n

i have a dual language site (English and Arabic). I have a view that has pix that link to different parts of the site. My problem is that when im not logged into the site and im in the arabic version and click on one of the view items, the site goes to the english part of the destination url even though there is a language = ar in the url. there is a %20 at the end of the URL as well. Below is a sample url: 
testsite/ndesign-content-v2/projects/commercial?language=ar%20

when I remove the %20 everything works fine. Please not that this doesnt happen for users that are logged in

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: `%20`is an encoded space. Look for somewhere in your code where a space is appended to the language string.

Comment: i did not use any custom code, just a content type and a view. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look at how the fields in your view is rendered. There may be a trailing space somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks loads my friend. Your guidance was spot on. I did some rewrite on the link field and there was a trailing space at the end. Problem was resolved when I removed the extra space. Many thanks